# Invoking global variables cause errors in function defined in .c file

Tags: c, function, header, global-variables, global

In a C program, when I have a set of global variables defined in the main.c file, how do I use their values in functions defined in different .c files? For example, the following files, when compiled using ***gcc -o my_prog main.c foo.c*** throws the following error:

```
foo.c: In function ‘foo’:
foo.c:5:9: error: ‘b’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h" 

int b=4;

int main(void)
{
    int y = foo(3);  /* Use the function here */
    printf("%d\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

foo.c

```
#include "foo.h"  

int foo(int x)    /* Function definition */
{
    return x + b;
}
```

foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H_   /* Include guard */
#define FOO_H_

int foo(int x);  /* An example function declaration */

#endif // FOO_H_
```

How do we get around this?

Comment: Add `int b;` to your `foo.h`.

Comment: Compiler doesn't know anything about `b` when compiling `foo.c`. Tell him something.

Comment: @EOF I would rather say `extern int b;`

Comment: so I have to declare the variable b twice?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Looking at C11 draft standard n1570, *6.9.2 External object definitions* it seems it will have external linkage. It may nevertheless be a good idea to make this explicit.

Comment: @EOF AFAIK the tentative definitions are working in the current translation unit only: "*A tentative definition becomes a full definition if the end of the translation unit is reached and no definition has appeared with an initializer for the identifier*". So It wont be tentative, but full.

Comment: @PintoDoido It would be a good idea for you to learn a bit about how compiler and linker are working together. Specifically read about `extern` keyword and wht it does.